# Typescript Error: Type 'any' is not a constructor function type

Tags: angular, typescript

I am currently trying out Angular 2 in combination with Ionic 2 so I am a bit new to TypeScript. Basically I was implementing a RESTService and I wanted to make the Rest Class abstract.

```
export abstract class RESTService{

   mHttp: Http;
   mParameters: Parameter[];
   mURL: string;

   constructor (private http: Http, private parameters: Parameter[]){
       this.mHttp = http;
       this.mParameters = parameters;
   }

   // URL of the Rest Service
   abstract getURL() : string;

   // Convert or handle the Response
   handleResponse(rawResponse: Response){
       let body = rawResponse.json();
       return body.data || { };
   }

   // Handle an error 
   abstract handleError(error: any);

   // Do the rest call
   makeCall(): Observable<any> {
       return this.mHttp.get(this.mURL).map(this.handleResponse).catch(this.handleError);
   }}
```

And here is the class which extends from the RESTService:

```
export class RESTServiceJourney extends RESTService{

   constructor(http:Http, parameters:Parameter[]){
       super(http, parameters);
   }

   // URL of the Rest Service
   getURL() : string {
        return "";
   }

   // Convert or handle the Response
   private handleResponse(rawResponse: Response){
       return "";
   }

   // Handle an error 
   private handleError(error: any){
       return "";
   }}
```

But I always get an ***Type 'any' is not a constructor function type*** error at the line "***export class RESTServiceJourney extends RESTService***". I searched through Google and Stackoverflow and do not know what kind of error this is. (I found one on Stackoverflow, but that one has problem with the version.)

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I made a mistake when importing the abstract class.

I wrote: **import { RESTService } from 'restService';**

But had to: **import { RESTService } from './restService';**

Comment: I mark upvote already..thanks, but after solve this problem one more error coming 'Cannot find module "./ionic-img-viewer"'

Comment: Where did you write the import? ionic-img-viewer has to be at the same level as the script where you defined your import.